# why is the dynamically allocated object going out of scope outside the function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to allocate objects on the heap according to a string entered by the user but I cannot access the pointers or objects outside the function although they are on the heap. As well, I tried to allocate them using unique pointers but I'm still getting an error saying "not declared" etc.

How can I create these objects, a user can create eight objects concurrently with spaces between the words. (e.g. "Avalanche Toolbox Paperdoll" and so on)?

```
   string user_input;
   getline(cin, user_input);

   istringstream iss(user_input);
   copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
   istream_iterator<string>(),
   back_inserter(vec));

     for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if(vec.at(i)=="Avalanche")
            {
                Avalanche *avalanche = new Avalanche(5);
                std::unique_ptr<Avalanche> ptr(new Avalanche(5)); // even tried using unique pointer.
                cout<<"Avalanche: "<<avalanche->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Bureaucrat")
            {
                Bureaucrat *bureaucrat = new Bureaucrat(5);
                cout<<"Bureaucrat: "<<bureaucrat->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Toolbox")
            {
                Toolbox *toolbox = new Toolbox(5);
                cout<<"Toolbox: "<<toolbox->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Crescendo")
            {
                Crescendo *crescendo = new Crescendo(5);
                cout<<"Crescendo: "<<crescendo->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Paperdoll")
            {
                Paperdoll *paperdoll = new Paperdoll(5);
                cout<<"Paperdoll: "<<paperdoll->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="FistfullODollars")
            {
                Fistfullodollars *fistfullodollars = new Fistfullodollars(5);
                cout<<"FistfullOdollars: "<<fistfullodollars->c_game<<endl;
            }
        }
        cout<<ptr.c_game<<endl; // give an error not declared
```

Comment: Creating objects on the heap doesn't mean that they're exempt from the normal scoping rules of C++. If you want to access an object created inside a function outside that function then the simplest way is to *return* that object from the function. This is true whether the object is created on the heap or not.

Comment: when i use return it give an error: invalid conversion from Object to int...

Comment: Then you must change the return type of the function.

Comment: Your extra problem is that you are trying to create objects of different types. You also need to create an inheritance hierarchy of your objects. I sense you are trying to do something that's a bit beyond your knowledge at the momemt

Comment: These classes are all inherited from Same parent class Called "Computer Player". how can i use templates to return specific type of object? i dont know how to use tempates... thanks

Comment: You are confusing scope (in which areas of a program a particular variable can be accessed) with extent (how long a particular object lives). Then there is the additional issue of the difference between a pointer and the object it is pointing to..

Comment: What do you actually want to _do_ with these dynamically allocated objects?

Comment: No templates are not the answer to this problem. As I said you need to use inheritance.

Comment: I am using inheritance, They are all derived classes of One base class.. and i am trying to make these objects and pass them to a method of another independent class.

Comment: OK, that's good, then make your function return a pointer to the base class (maybe a smart pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Your object lifetime is limited to it's scope.  In your case, the scope is within two closest {}. You need to remember that when you have a (smart)pointer to allocated memory, you actually have TWO objects - one is your (smart) pointer, and the other is the object the pointer points to. When the pointer goes out of scope, you can not reference the actual object by this pointer anymore. And if there is no other pointer pointing to this object, the object is lost forever, and you have is a classic example of so called memory leak - there is an object somewhere there, but is unaccessible, and the memory occupied by it is lost and can not be reused.
Think about it in a following way - you have a book and a library card. The book is somewhere in the vast storage, and unless you know where to look (using library card) you will never find it. So if you lost all copies of your library cards, the book is as good as lost to you - though it is obviously somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, that your objects created are not deleted, since you have created them on the heap, as you pointed out, but the pointer variables go out of scope. The solution is, to put the declaration outside of the scopes and do the assignment in the scope:

```
   string user_input;
   getline(cin, user_input);

   istringstream iss(user_input);
   copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
   istream_iterator<string>(),
   back_inserter(vec));

   Bureaucrat *bureaucrat;
   Toolbox *toolbox;
   Crescendo *crescendo;
   Paperdoll *paperdoll;
   Fistfullodollars *fistfullodollars;

     for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            if(vec.at(i)=="Avalanche")
            {
                Avalanche *avalanche = new Avalanche(5);
                std::unique_ptr<Avalanche> ptr(new Avalanche(5)); // even tried using unique pointer.
                cout<<"Avalanche: "<<avalanche->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Bureaucrat")
            {
                bureaucrat = new Bureaucrat(5);
                cout<<"Bureaucrat: "<<bureaucrat->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Toolbox")
            {
                toolbox = new Toolbox(5);
                cout<<"Toolbox: "<<toolbox->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Crescendo")
            {
                crescendo = new Crescendo(5);
                cout<<"Crescendo: "<<crescendo->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="Paperdoll")
            {
                paperdoll = new Paperdoll(5);
                cout<<"Paperdoll: "<<paperdoll->c_game<<endl;
            }
            else if(vec.at(i)=="FistfullODollars")
            {
                fistfullodollars = new Fistfullodollars(5);
                cout<<"FistfullOdollars: "<<fistfullodollars->c_game<<endl;
            }
        }
        cout<<ptr.c_game<<endl; // give an error not declared
```

Comment: Oh i see. i was getting the error because o the Loop

Comment: we have allocated just one pointer of each class. what is the User wants to create 5 Avalanche objects. ? Should i store them in array of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is declared on the stack, it's the object *it's pointing at* which is `delete` bound. 
when `if(vec.at(i)=="Avalanche") {}` is over, `ptr` (which is stack allocated) gets out of scope and no longer accesible.

Comment: ptr should be declared int he first lines of the function if you want to excess it in the last line. but your error is becuase your trying to read iutside the range of your vector. this is not pointer-scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you allocate your object dynamically you still need a pointer variable to keep track of where that memory is. Your `ptr` variable is destroyed at the end of the enclosing braces.

I'm guessing all your classes `Avalanche`, `Bureaucrat`... inherit from some base class with a `c_game` member variable. Perhaps something a bit like this:

```
struct MyBase {
    virtual ~MyBase(){}  // This is important!
    MyBase(std::string c_game) : c_game(c_game) {}
    std::string c_game;
};

struct Avalanche : public MyBase {
    Avalanche(int num) : MyBase("Avalanche"), num(num) {}
    int num;
};

struct Fistfullodollars : public MyBase {
    Fistfullodollars(int num) : MyBase("Fistfullodollars"), num(num) {}
    int num;
};

//...
```

In order to keep track of these dynamically allocated objects you could construct a container of (smart) pointers to this base class:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> objects;

for(size_t i=0; i!=vec.size(); i++)
{
    if(vec.at(i)=="Avalanche")
    {
        objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Avalanche>(5));
        std::cout<<"Avalanche: "<<objects.back()->c_game<<"\n";
    }
    else if(vec.at(i)=="FistfullODollars")
    {
        objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Fistfullodollars>(5));
        std::cout<<"FistfullOdollars: "<<objects.back()->c_game<<"\n";
    }
    //...
}

for (const auto& ptr : objects)
{
    std::cout << ptr->c_game << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MOwJmZi4tovBKz1c)